# Retreiving value from node in parent level

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I am having trouble retrieving value in node UsagePoin/mRID that is child of node MeterReading and sibling of node IntervalBlocks.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xml_data XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xml_data) VALUES
(N'<RequestMessage xmlns="http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/schema/message" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Message.xsd">
  <Header>
    <Verb>create</Verb>
    <Noun>MeterReadings</Noun>
    <Timestamp>2022-01-09T01:00:58+01:00</Timestamp>
    <Source>Y</Source>
    <AsyncReplyFlag>true</AsyncReplyFlag>
    <AckRequired>true</AckRequired>
    <MessageID>xyz_9999</MessageID>
    <CorrelationID></CorrelationID>
  </Header>
  <Payload>
    <MeterReadings xmlns="http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/MeterReadings#" xmlns:MeterReadings="http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/MeterReadings#">
      <MeterReading>
        <IntervalBlocks>
          <IntervalReadings>
            <source>999</source>
            <timeStamp>2022-01-08T00:00:00.000+01:00</timeStamp>
            <value>9.246</value>
            <ReadingQualities>
              <ReadingQualityType ref="3.0.0" />
            </ReadingQualities>
          </IntervalReadings>
          <IntervalReadings>
            <source>999</source>
            <timeStamp>2022-01-08T01:00:00.000+01:00</timeStamp>
            <value>10.404</value>
            <ReadingQualities>
              <ReadingQualityType ref="3.0.0" />
            </ReadingQualities>
          </IntervalReadings>
          <ReadingType ref="11.0.7.1.1.2.12.1.1.0.0.0.0.1010.0.3.72.0" />
        </IntervalBlocks>
        <Meter>
          <mRID>209558305</mRID>
        </Meter>
        <UsagePoint>
          <mRID>735999999999999999</mRID>
        </UsagePoint>
      </MeterReading>
      <MeterReading>
        <IntervalBlocks>
          <IntervalReadings>
            <source>999</source>
            <timeStamp>2022-01-08T00:00:00.000+01:00</timeStamp>
            <value>2.46</value>
            <ReadingQualities>
              <ReadingQualityType ref="3.0.0" />
            </ReadingQualities>
          </IntervalReadings>
          <IntervalReadings>
            <source>999</source>
            <timeStamp>2022-01-08T01:00:00.000+01:00</timeStamp>
            <value>2.52</value>
            <ReadingQualities>
              <ReadingQualityType ref="3.0.0" />
            </ReadingQualities>
          </IntervalReadings>
          <IntervalReadings>
            <source>999</source>
            <timeStamp>2022-01-08T02:00:00.000+01:00</timeStamp>
            <value>2.502</value>
            <ReadingQualities>
              <ReadingQualityType ref="3.0.0" />
            </ReadingQualities>
          </IntervalReadings>
          <ReadingType ref="11.0.7.1.1.2.12.1.1.0.0.0.0.1102.0.3.73.0" />
        </IntervalBlocks>
        <Meter>
          <mRID>999999999</mRID>
        </Meter>
        <UsagePoint>
          <mRID>735999999999999999</mRID>
        </UsagePoint>
      </MeterReading>
    </MeterReadings>
      </Payload>
</RequestMessage>');
```

So I am using the following code.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(N'http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/schema/message' as hdr,
                   N'http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/MeterReadings#' as mr)
SELECT
    --t.file_name,t.file_created_time received_timestamp,
    --h.value('(hdr:Timestamp)[1]', 'nvarchar(35)') AS created_timestamp,
    --h.value('(hdr:MessageID)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS message_id,
    ir.value('(mr:timeStamp/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(35)') interval_timestamp,
    ir.value('(mr:value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(35)') interval_value,
    ir.value('(mr:ReadingQualities/mr:ReadingQualityType/@ref)[1]', 'nvarchar(35)') interval_value_code
FROM
    load.capgemeni_sesp_xml t
OUTER APPLY
    t.xml_data.nodes('/hdr:RequestMessage/hdr:Header') AS m(h)
--OUTER APPLY
--    t.xml_data.nodes('/hdr:RequestMessage/hdr:Payload/mr:MeterReadings/mr:MeterReading') AS MeterReading(mr)
OUTER APPLY
    t.xml_data.nodes('/hdr:RequestMessage/hdr:Payload/mr:MeterReadings/mr:MeterReading/mr:IntervalBlocks/mr:IntervalReadings') AS IntervalReadings(ir)
where t.file_name = 'SESP_32717237.xml'
AND ir.value('(mr:timeStamp/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(35)') = '2022-01-08T00:00:00.000+01:00'
```

It gives me output for each timestamp = '2022-01-08T00:00:00.000+01:00'. Now i need to add the UsagePoint and the ReadingType nodes. Both of them are in parent node level.

I tried traversing up hierarchy using following

```
ir.value('(./mr:ReadingType/@ref)[1]','nvarchar(35)')
```

It doesn't work. I assumed using ./ would traverse up from within node IntervalReadings to being within node IntervalBlocks and then it should be mr:ReadingType to traverse into node ReadingType and then @ref for getting the value in the "ref" tag.

I can't figure out why it isn't working. I am having similar issue with getting data from node mRID which is within node UsagePoint which is sibling to node IntervalBlocks within node MeterReading. For each UsagePoint can be 1 or more ReadingType which then have interval values on same level.

Whatever working solution I find for ReadingType will be able to be used to also get values for UsagePoint.

EDIT: To clarify i can produce out that looks like this...
[image]
It is showing values for the timestamp '2022-01-08T00:00:00.000+01:00' but i can't add ReadingType or UsagePoint correctly. When i for example try to add ReadingType i get null...
[image]

EDIT2:
For each IntervalBlocks node you have IntervalReadings node which then has x amount of interval values and on same level as IntervalBlocks node you will have the UsagePoint for the values and within the IntervalBlocks node on same level as IntervalReadings will have 1 or more ReadingType node. The ReadingType will be after a payload of values signifying the ReadingType is for that batch of values. 1 UsagePoint can have up to 4 ReadingType values.
I should have clarified data modell by having at least 2 UsagePoint and 2 ReadingType in the XML.

I am running SQL Server 2019.
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU14) (KB5007182) - 15.0.4188.2 (X64)   Nov  3 2021 19:19:51   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Please edit your question and add a desired output for a given XML.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky i have added now workin DDL that others can copy into SSMS. They can then just do sql select statement to help with producing desired output.

Comment: #3 is still missing. Please delete images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xml_data XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xml_data) VALUES
(N'<RequestMessage xmlns="http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/schema/message" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Message.xsd">
    <Header>
        <Verb>create</Verb>
        <Noun>MeterReadings</Noun>
        <Timestamp>2022-01-09T01:00:58+01:00</Timestamp>
        <Source>Y</Source>
        <AsyncReplyFlag>true</AsyncReplyFlag>
        <AckRequired>true</AckRequired>
        <MessageID>xyz_9999</MessageID>
        <CorrelationID></CorrelationID>
        <Property>
            <Name>CONTRACT</Name>
            <Value>xxxx</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>DIVISION</Name>
            <Value>01</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>RECEIVER</Name>
            <Value>xxx</Value>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>SERVICE</Name>
            <Value>xxxx</Value>
        </Property>
    </Header>
    <Payload>
        <MeterReadings xmlns="http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/MeterReadings#" xmlns:MeterReadings="http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/MeterReadings#">
            <MeterReading>
                <IntervalBlocks>
                    <IntervalReadings>
                        <source>x</source>
                        <timeStamp>2022-01-08T00:00:00.000+01:00</timeStamp>
                        <value>9.246</value>
                        <ReadingQualities>
                            <ReadingQualityType ref="3.0.0"/>
                        </ReadingQualities>
                    </IntervalReadings>
                    <IntervalReadings>
                        <source>x</source>
                        <timeStamp>2022-01-08T01:00:00.000+01:00</timeStamp>
                        <value>10.404</value>
                        <ReadingQualities>
                            <ReadingQualityType ref="3.0.0"/>
                        </ReadingQualities>
                    </IntervalReadings>
                    <ReadingType ref="11.0.7.1.1.2.12.1.1.0.0.0.0.1010.0.3.72.0"/>
                </IntervalBlocks>
                <IntervalBlocks>
                    <IntervalReadings>
                        <source>x</source>
                        <timeStamp>2022-01-08T00:00:00.000+01:00</timeStamp>
                        <value>9.246</value>
                        <ReadingQualities>
                            <ReadingQualityType ref="3.0.0"/>
                        </ReadingQualities>
                    </IntervalReadings>
                    <IntervalReadings>
                        <source>x</source>
                        <timeStamp>2022-01-08T01:00:00.000+01:00</timeStamp>
                        <value>10.404</value>
                        <ReadingQualities>
                            <ReadingQualityType ref="3.0.0"/>
                        </ReadingQualities>
                    </IntervalReadings>
                    <ReadingType ref="11.0.7.1.1.2.12.1.1.0.0.0.0.1102.0.3.72.0"/>
                </IntervalBlocks>
                <Meter>
                    <mRID>xxxx</mRID>
                </Meter>
                <UsagePoint>
                    <mRID>zzzz</mRID>
                </UsagePoint>
            </MeterReading>
            <MeterReading>
                <IntervalBlocks>
                    <IntervalReadings>
                        <source>x</source>
                        <timeStamp>2022-01-08T00:00:00.000+01:00</timeStamp>
                        <value>9.246</value>
                        <ReadingQualities>
                            <ReadingQualityType ref="3.0.0"/>
                        </ReadingQualities>
                    </IntervalReadings>
                    <IntervalReadings>
                        <source>x</source>
                        <timeStamp>2022-01-08T01:00:00.000+01:00</timeStamp>
                        <value>10.404</value>
                        <ReadingQualities>
                            <ReadingQualityType ref="3.0.0"/>
                        </ReadingQualities>
                    </IntervalReadings>
                    <ReadingType ref="11.0.7.1.1.2.12.1.1.0.0.0.0.1010.0.3.72.0"/>
                </IntervalBlocks>
                <IntervalBlocks>
                    <IntervalReadings>
                        <source>x</source>
                        <timeStamp>2022-01-08T00:00:00.000+01:00</timeStamp>
                        <value>9.246</value>
                        <ReadingQualities>
                            <ReadingQualityType ref="3.0.0"/>
                        </ReadingQualities>
                    </IntervalReadings>
                    <IntervalReadings>
                        <source>x</source>
                        <timeStamp>2022-01-08T01:00:00.000+01:00</timeStamp>
                        <value>10.404</value>
                        <ReadingQualities>
                            <ReadingQualityType ref="3.0.0"/>
                        </ReadingQualities>
                    </IntervalReadings>
                    <ReadingType ref="11.0.7.1.1.2.12.1.1.0.0.0.0.1102.0.3.72.0"/>
                </IntervalBlocks>
                <Meter>
                    <mRID>kkkkk</mRID>
                </Meter>
                <UsagePoint>
                    <mRID>qqqqq</mRID>
                </UsagePoint>
            </MeterReading>
        </MeterReadings>
    </Payload>
</RequestMessage>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(N'http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/schema/message' as hdr,
                   N'http://iec.ch/TC57/2011/MeterReadings#' as mr)
SELECT
    --t.file_name,t.file_created_time received_timestamp,
    --h.value('(hdr:Timestamp)[1]', 'nvarchar(35)') AS created_timestamp,
    --h.value('(hdr:MessageID)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS message_id,
     ir.value('(mr:timeStamp/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(35)') interval_timestamp
    , ir.value('(mr:value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(35)') interval_value
    , ir.value('(mr:ReadingQualities/mr:ReadingQualityType/@ref)[1]', 'nvarchar(35)') interval_value_code
    , mr.value('(mr:UsagePoint/mr:mRID/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') UsagePoint 
    , ir.value('(../mr:ReadingType/@ref)[1]', 'nvarchar(35)') ReadingType
FROM @tbl t
OUTER APPLY t.xml_data.nodes('/hdr:RequestMessage/hdr:Header') AS m(h)
OUTER APPLY t.xml_data.nodes('/hdr:RequestMessage/hdr:Payload/mr:MeterReadings/mr:MeterReading') AS MeterReading(mr)
OUTER APPLY MeterReading.mr.nodes('mr:IntervalBlocks/mr:IntervalReadings') AS IntervalReadings(ir)
--WHERE --t.file_name = 'SESP_32717237.xml' AND 
--  ir.value('(mr:timeStamp/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(35)') = '2022-01-08T00:00:00.000+01:00'
```

**Output**

```
+-------------------------------+----------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------------------+
|      interval_timestamp       | interval_value | interval_value_code | UsagePoint |             ReadingType             |
+-------------------------------+----------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------------------+
| 2022-01-08T00:00:00.000+01:00 |          9.246 |               3.0.0 | zzzz       | 11.0.7.1.1.2.12.1.1.0.0.0.0.1010.0. |
| 2022-01-08T01:00:00.000+01:00 |         10.404 |               3.0.0 | zzzz       | 11.0.7.1.1.2.12.1.1.0.0.0.0.1010.0. |
| 2022-01-08T00:00:00.000+01:00 |          9.246 |               3.0.0 | zzzz       | 11.0.7.1.1.2.12.1.1.0.0.0.0.1102.0. |
| 2022-01-08T01:00:00.000+01:00 |         10.404 |               3.0.0 | zzzz       | 11.0.7.1.1.2.12.1.1.0.0.0.0.1102.0. |
| 2022-01-08T00:00:00.000+01:00 |          9.246 |               3.0.0 | qqqqq      | 11.0.7.1.1.2.12.1.1.0.0.0.0.1010.0. |
| 2022-01-08T01:00:00.000+01:00 |         10.404 |               3.0.0 | qqqqq      | 11.0.7.1.1.2.12.1.1.0.0.0.0.1010.0. |
| 2022-01-08T00:00:00.000+01:00 |          9.246 |               3.0.0 | qqqqq      | 11.0.7.1.1.2.12.1.1.0.0.0.0.1102.0. |
| 2022-01-08T01:00:00.000+01:00 |         10.404 |               3.0.0 | qqqqq      | 11.0.7.1.1.2.12.1.1.0.0.0.0.1102.0. |
+-------------------------------+----------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for trying to help. Unfortunately i get carthesian product. For each IntervalBlocks node you have IntervalReadings node which then has x amount of interval values and on same level as IntervalBlocks node you will have the UsagePoint for the values and within the IntervalBlocks node on same level as IntervalReadings  will have 1 or more ReadingType node. The ReadingType  will be after a payload of values signifying the ReadingType  is for that batch of values. 1 UsagePoint can have up to 4 ReadingType values.

Comment: Partly my fault for not including in XML more than 1 UsagePoint and ReadingType.

Comment: Please see @YitzhakKhabinsky comment.

Comment: I have added now working DDL that you can copy and query against. You can see your code gives duplication issue(carthesian product). I think the key is to be able to traverse up hierarchy and then into the mr:ReadingType node and mr:UsagePoint node. If start at the most granular node i believe won't get carthesian product if able to get value from higer level node.

Comment: I adjusted the answer. Check it out.

Comment: It works except for ReadingType. When i run it against the XML i provided it doesn't throw exception but when i run it against db stored XMLs it throws following exception for ReadingType...

`Msg 2389, Level 16, State 1, Line 443
XQuery [load.capgemeni_sesp_xml.xml_data.value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:anyAtomicType *'
`

Comment: Adjusted. Please try it now. Hopefully, you appreciate now value of a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241803/discussion-between-mattias-w-and-miriamka).

Comment: Thank you @miriamka for helping me solve this. Very cool thing to be able to use the dot thing to find out which context it is working of currently. Helps alot with debugging.